# ionic : load a div without using window.location.reload()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, ionic-framework

I develop a mobile application using ionic. when someone authentificate, I save his data locally using `localStorage` and show these information in a div .but when another person want to authentificate after him, the div contains the old informaion .the new data shows if I refresh the page using `window.location.reload()` .

I want to show the new data without refreshing the page !!

```
 <div class="bloc" id="bloc">
         <h2>{{nom}}  {{prenom}}</h2>
         <p>login : {{login}} </p>
         <p>password : {{pass}} </p><br>
         <button class="button icon-right ion-edit  button-royal rightSide" ng-click="modifier()" id="activateB">Modifier</button>
   </div>
```

my controller :

```
.controller('ConfigController',['$scope','$http','$state','sharedProperties',function($scope,$http,$state,sharedProperties){

     $scope.init=function() {

       document.getElementById('formulaire').style.display = 'none';
        var data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage['user'] || '{}');      
        $scope.idpersonne=data['id'];
        $scope.nom=data['nom'];
        $scope.prenom=data['prenom'];
        $scope.login=data['login'];
        $scope.pass=data['pass'];
        $scope.admin=data['admin'];
     }
}])
```

Comment: You will have to remove it from local storage on logout.

Comment: Might not be a good approach but you can try saving user information to $rootScope. You probably won't lose information while loading a page.

Comment: @smk .. I did it with window.localStorage.clear(); but as I said, the object "data" contains the new data but i should make a refresh to show it !!

Comment: @denden130 .. my problem is not about losing information because I don't lose it .. I wanna just make a refresh to my div to show the new information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run `$ionicHistory.clearCache();` in your controller when a user logout. Which will clear all view cache for a user. `cache-view="false"` does not clear cache, it disables cache. Means with `cache-view="false"` view cache was never implemented, controller and view were loaded every time. Read document of [$ionicHistory](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/)

And if you want to disable cache view for some particular view then use `cache-view` attribute in `<ion-view>`.

You can also disable or enable cache from routes like this

```
.state('example', {
      url: '/example',
      cache: false,
      templateUrl: 'templates/example.html',
      controller: 'exampleCtrl'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

problem solved .. I should just add  `cache-view="false"` in my `ion-view` , now once you log out ionic clean the cache

Comment: It did not clear cache, it disabled cache on your view. http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/ see `cache-view` attribute description

Comment: now , I should just add $ionicHistory.clearCache(); without adding cache-view="false" ?? isn't ?! @MudasserAjaz

Comment: Yes, depends on your requirement. `clearCache` will clear whole views cache. It is better to add this when user logout from your application.